# what is the name of the convention used in this syntax diagram

Tags: json, diagram, specifications, bnf

I found this diagram in the JSON specification:

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/array.gif))</sub>

Where does this diagramming convention come from? Is it just some random convention cooked up by D.C.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That diagram is known as a [syntax diagram or railroad diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram). It's used to visually represent context-free grammars. It's a graphical depiction of [the Extended Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus-Naur_form), which is also used to represent context-free grammars.

Answer (score 5):

That's called a railroad diagram.  Have a look at the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) for more information.